# Gnome/Elf Children's movie

Tags: story-identification

My sister and I grew up in the 90s and I always remembered this film we watched that was animated about a gnome/elf family I really don't remember much but it had a brother and sister and I think they had dark hair. They lived in a forest I think in a tree and had adventures in the forest. I'm sorry it's not much help but the animation was beautiful and I always enjoyed it.

Comment: Did they fight trolls and drug them,  and then stick spoons in their noses?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_of_David_the_Gnome

Comment: Is the family preparing for the wedding of their oldest son?

Answer (score 3):

Is it [The Little Twins](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/TheLittleTwins)? I was searching for the same movie with a similar description as yours that I watched growing up. Been searching for a good 6 months haha!